# Как интегрировать массовые выплаты от яндекс.касса на сайт?

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

Есть самописный сайт на yii2. Нужно реализовать там возможность выплаты денег на карты пользователям от сервиса Яндекс.Касса. Платёжный сервис выбирал не я, и он уже утверждён, в яндексе уже утвердили возможность интеграции, и вот последние несколько дней я пытаюсь сделать возможность выплаты денег. В их документации, конечно, всё написано, но кто бы понял что там написано. Нет ни одного примера. В интернете куча статей о том что в тех. поддержке никто не поможет и даже не стоит туда обращаться. Может быть кто нибудь делал массовые выплаты (makeDeposition) от яндекс.кассы и поделится хотя бы каким то примером интеграции? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего никак. У нас есть куча iot устройств и нам были нужны массовые выплаты (пополнения симок - список из 200 номеров, который не меняется). Долго переписывались с поддержкой Яндекса, они считают это фродом и рисковать не хотят. В итоге перешли на e-post и sotplat.ru